# How to delete element in object by index in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have object: `$scope.formData = {}`

How I can delete element in object by `$index`:

```
 $scope.formData.university[$index];
```

I tried:

```
$scope.formData.university.splice($index);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **'delete'** operator. For more info Refer [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

```
 delete  $scope.formData.university[$index];
```

Answer (score 1):

It should have [**slice**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) first parameter as `$index` & then second one would be `1`

```
$scope.formData.university.splice($index, 1);
```

> **Note:** using `$index` for deleting element would be risky if you are applying filtering on `ng-repeat`

Instead of that you could add some unique prop in your each element of `ng-repeat` you could add `id` in it, so that while deleting you could pass that id and then do find index of that element and delete that element from an array like the same way I did wrote above code.

Comment: TypeError: $scope.formData.university.splice is not a function

Comment: @Ahmed does `$scope.formData.university` has values?

Comment: Yes, has value: `Object {0: "nnnnnn", 1: "jkjbbubiuiu"}`